# Ray's module: _raylet.so compile from where?

Tags: ray

I am debugging the Ray source code, but I find the code destination is the _raylet.so . Where is _raylet.so compile from? Can you tell me where is the source code in the https://github.com/ray-project/ray?

I use the `pip install ray` in the centOS7, _raylet.so is in this path: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray

Answer (score 0):

The bazel target is defined here https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/BUILD.bazel#L2064 and you can find related file according to the target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok, I find it, thanks